# Always showing video controls

Tags: html, video

Is there a way to Always show the video controls in the HTML5 video tag instead of just showing them on MouseOver?

Video code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td runat="server" width="680px" height="383px" id="vContainer">
      <div style="z-index: 1;" runat="server" id="cont">
        <div runat="server" style="background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6) url('/images/Play.png') no-repeat center center;" id="img">
        </div>
        <video id="player" style="z-index: 1; border: 1px solid #000000;" width="100%" height="100% "
          title="" controls runat="server">
          <source runat="server" id="ffVideo" type="video/ogg" />
          <source runat="server" id="mp4Video" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <embed id="playerOld" width="680px" height="383px" autostart="false" allowfullscreen="true"
          title="" style="display: none" type="application/mp4" runat="server" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table
```

>

Comment: You can found solution on [this post].[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384276/videojs-keep-controls-visible

Comment: My question is about the HTML5 video tag not the Javascript Library VideoJS...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Update November 2017: Please note due to new changes in Safari 11, this is no longer working in that browser. I will update the post if I find a way.

Even though hiding controls is part of the HTML5 video spec. There are two ways to accomplish this one via javascript and the other via CSS.

In Javascript, you can add an event handler for the timeupdate event which changes every time the play position has changed, in other words, the event is always occurring while the video is playing.

Assuming the id for the video element is called 'player', javascript code would look like this:

JS:

```
//assign video element to variable vid
var vid = document.getElementById("player");

function videoTimeUpdate(e)
{
    //set controls settings to controls,this make controls show everytime this event is triggered
    vid.setAttribute("controls","controls");
}

//add event listener to video for timeupdate event
vid.addEventListener('timeupdate', videoTimeUpdate, false);
```

Working sample of the above is here: https://jsfiddle.net/l33tstealth/t082bjnf/6/

The second way to do this is through CSS but this will only work for `WebKit` based browsers, thus limited. You can force the controls bar to always show.

The CSS for that would look like this:

CSS:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    display: flex !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Working sample (only works in web kit based browsers):
https://jsfiddle.net/l33tstealth/t082bjnf/7/

Comment: This got me out of a jam. Used the css one since our app is accessed local via chrome browsers only.

Comment: both solutions did not work for me in a current safari (11.0.1).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will update my post. Tried to find a way to make it work but seems like the new changes on Safari 11 not allowing for this, I will be on the lookout. If you or anyone knows of a way please comment.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!  I switched it some to use jQuery's "on( 'timeupdate' )" and an anonymous function callback using "$(this).prop('controls','controls')".

Comment: Ugh, my controls now won't even turn on after I remove this code.  There must be something in Firefox which much be caching the video tag.

Comment: Just an addition to the accepted answer - here is my one-liner ```<video controls ontimeupdate="this.setAttribute('controls', true)"></video>```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
function keepControls () {
  video.removeAttribute('controls')
  video.setAttribute('controls', '')
}

video.addEventListener('timeupdate', keepControls)
```

The trick is to remove the controls and add them again quickly enough to look like they never disappear.