# how to make the video of html5 controls to be visible always?

Tags: html, html5-video

The default of the video controles visibility is to be shown on hover. 
i want to make it visible always

I can't find any way to do it. 
How this can be possible from the code or css ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this. I think you have the same question

[Always showing video controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246435/always-showing-video-controls)

Or you can use this css:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
   display: flex !important;
   opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

It does have an answer. hopefully it helps