# how to make html5 video controls always on/show .?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video, html5-video

how to make html5 video controls always on/show (without mouse hover) .? currently the video controls show only on mouse hover while playing video. i have tried "controls:true" attribute but which does not help in video tag. looking for latest Chrome and Fire fox browsers implementation.

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls="true">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: it's probably a browser (chrome/ff/other) feature... so I guess to always show "controls" you need to create buttons in HTML (and bind proper eventhandlers, obviously)...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43145210/11283638 This might help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Always showing video controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32246435/always-showing-video-controls)

Comment: @M.Mavini Nope it didn't help with latest chrome browser.

Comment: @krish Comment it there no need for new question.