# How to always show video player controls on html5 video player

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, video

I am using html video player. I want to show control bar always ..currently it shows on hover but i want it should be display always not only on hover.

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30856986/866439

Answer (score 0):

Include the **controls** attribute to the video player

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

For me adding the control tag *always* shows the controls in Chrome. Are you using other browser like Safari?

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: I had already put this attribute "control"...my main issue is it shows only on hover...but i want it should be display always not only on hover...

Comment: What is the browser that you are using?

Comment: I am using  crome

Comment: Can you share the CSS/JS for the player?

Comment: I am not using any external css or js ...kept default ....example which u shared above same i am using ...

Comment: in the case of chrome, show controls  when hover only....

Comment: may be this link help you -> https://freshman.tech/custom-html5-video/